# In need of help concerning making a knot animation (paths etc.)

Tags: path

I'm in need of help to get the same result as the one shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gk5tOOD_ArY&t=39s . I'm wondering if there's a guide how to make something like this. Please help.

My main problem is parenting the rope to a path so that the whole rope follows/curves along the path.

Comment: I find the sliding rope-texture in your reference _really_ distracting. It severely impairs communication of the central point of the graphic: how the knots are formed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to move the rope, Depending on how you construct the rope you could animate either the Bevel Factor or the Dupliframes end frame, and have the rope 'grow' along the path.  It seems that this is what they've done in the linked video.  Albeit with some rotation to make it appear to be moving.

[image: Bevel Factor Option]

[image: Animation Example]

Comment: Is there maybe a more in depth guide to something like this? I'm not good at all in blender at least right now. The creator in the comments said he did it like this: " Basically, I made a 3 leaf clover shape in 2D. Then used a Screw modifier. Then added a curve deform by parenting it to a path.". Thank you.